# Non-constant variable in a ClickOnce installation URL

Tags: c#, wcf, installation, clickonce

I have a ClickOnce application where I am overriding the standard ClickOnce updating system and creating my own within the application with the code on this page.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/walkthrough-creating-a-custom-installer-for-a-clickonce-application

The Application uses a logon to a webservice I control. The install files need to be protected from download by anyone who does not have an account in the webservice. I'm using the following method to try to do this:

Once the user logs into the application, a random Guid is generated as part of the user information (this was part of the system long before this issue arose). It is stored both in the database and in the application. After the login, the application calls a function on the webservice that logs the username, guid, client IP address, and an expiration time that is the current time plus five minutes. After that, the application contacts the download web site to retrieve the manifest. It includes with this the generated guid as a querystring parameter. The website intercepts the request and verifies the IP address and expiration time, and if they match, feeds a stream of the requested files back to the application.

My problem is that including the guid in the querystring makes it part of the installation URL, and ClickOnce expects it to be the same the next time the application is updated.

Is there any way to have the querystring included in the call, but not have it be part of the installation URL? Or is there some other way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be better to not put limits on *who can download what* and instead move security to when the *application runs*?

Then the base ClickOnce download URL becomes **static** (which is what ClickOnce was designed for) and the problem goes away.

Comment: Believe me. I'm of the same opinion as you, but management has different ideas.

Comment: No, because the code download is likely to be valuable or sensitive. A motivated attacker can download your code from the static URL and use a disassembler to remove whatever licensing or copy protection code you have put in place.

Comment: @HughW that fear is applicable to _any_ code.

Comment: @Deleted absolutely. That's why I say the answer to "Wouldn't it be better to not put limits on who can download what and instead move security to when the application runs?" in many cases is 'no'.

Comment: @HughW works for Kerberos and CAS.